# Testing CKErrorChangeTokenExpired handling by generating known expired CKServerChangeToken

Tags: ios, objective-c, cloudkit

The header comment on `CKFetchDatabaseChangesOperation` `fetchDatabaseChangesCompletionBlock` states:

*"If the server returns a `CKErrorChangeTokenExpired` error, the `previousServerChangeToken` value was too old and the client should toss its local cache and
 re-fetch the changes in this record zone starting with a nil `previousServerChangeToken`."*

I would like to test this scenario thus I would like to generate an expired `CKServerChangeToken` so I can set it as the `previousServerChangeToken` on a `CKFetchDatabaseChangesOperation`.

I added an init method from the private header:

```
@interface CKServerChangeToken (Private)
    - (id)initWithData:(NSData *)data;
@end
```

And used it as follows:

```
CKServerChangeToken knownExpiredToken = [[CKServerChangeToken alloc] initWithData:[[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:@"AQAAAVl57tUGHv6sgNT9EeaTcQCM+sDHHA==" options:0]];
```

That string is a valid change token returned from a request and I have tried unsuccessfully modifying it, e.g. reducing numbers that I see incrementing to lower ones. I have however managed to get another strange invalid argument errors like continuation marker missing. I would be grateful if a CloudKit engineer has any suggestions, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old post, but I've unintentionally generated `.changeTokenExpired` errors by doing this:

1. Fetch changes and save your change token.
2. In the dashboard, delete the zone you're syncing with.
3. Create a new zone with the same name.
4. In your code, fetch changes again, using the change token from step 1.

Since the token refers to a different zone, it doesn't make any sense to CloudKit, which returns a `.changeTokenExpired` error.

Answer (score 0):

It would be really nice if Apple provided a way to do this, because it's an absolutely crucial situation to test.

I couldn't find any recommended way to do this, so I used tokens generated for other zones. If you've got multiple zones like I did, you can effectively cross wire token retrieval. It's not an elegant solution, but it does work... :)